# Can I turn a $variable into a table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I followed an online tutorial to create an admin back-end and I ended up with this code before the HTML tags of the php page:

```
<?php 
$product_list = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount

if ($productCount > 0)
{
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  { 
    $id = $row["id"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
    $product_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - $$price - <em>Added $date_added</em> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br />";
  }
} 
else 
{
  $product_list = "You have no products listed in your store yet";
}
?>
```

When I put the `<?php echo $product_list; ?>` on the page content I retreive a list result like this:

```
Product ID: 1 - Strawberries - $10 - Added Mar 22, 2013       edit • delete
Product ID: 2 - Apples 1 - $10 - Added Mar 22, 2013       edit • delete
```

What I want is to put it in a symmetrical list view like with a table or so to present the results and the edit/delete option. Tried to put a table with 1 row and 5 columns on `$product_list` with no success.

Comment: Are you asking about how to add `<table>` and `<td>` tags in your output?

Comment: no. when i create a new product the page of inventory items refresh giving me all the products of my database but in that format on a "line of text". what i need is to put that results in some sort of listview like a table. but i cant manage to manipulate that code to do it. (noob in the house, sorry)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: This question is lacking the `html` tag.

Comment: well... the tutorial is from 2010 and im starting with php. thanks for the heads up about the MySQLi. Guided by the tutorial i already create a script to connect to the database that i included in other <?php tag> above the code i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name");

$query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$product_list = '<table>';
$product_list .= '<thead><tr>ID</tr><tr>Name</tr><tr>Price</tr><tr>Added</tr></thead>';
$product_list .= '<tbody>';

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){ 
  $id = $row["id"];
  $product_name = $row["product_name"];
  $price = $row["price"];
  $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
  $product_list .= "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$product_name</td><td>$price</td>    <td>$date_added</td></tr>";
 }

 $product_list .= '</tbody>';
 $product_list .= '</table>';

 echo $product_list;
```

Comment: Good answer, but switch to MYSQLI or PDO.

Comment: Agreed. Let me rewrite it.

Comment: thanks. i replaced the code you wrote and came up with this errors: Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /home/mutesoft/public_html/fStore/admin/inventory_list.php on line 80

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /home/mutesoft/public_html/fStore/admin/inventory_list.php on line 86

Comment: and i already have this: include "../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; above that code to connect to the database

Comment: truly sorry, edited the query. it should be just "select.." I had mysql_query("... left over from the old version.

Comment: you have to apologise. its me who thanks for your help. with my "connect_to_mysql.php" script included do i still have to use the [ $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name"); ] line?

Comment: This is the new way of doing mysql connections. replace your current mysql connect code inside connect_to_mysql.php with the $mysqli = new mysqli line. I hope it all went well.

Comment: connect_to_mysql.php code: <?php  

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "...";
$db_pass = "...";
$db_name = "..."; 
mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");              
?>

Comment: Have this connect_to_mysql: <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mutesoft_admin", "kykkygod", "mutesoft_kykky");

// Run the actual connection here  
$myConnection= mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 
mysqli_select_db("mutesoft_kykky") or die ("no database");                
?>  BUT I GET THIS ERROR: Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'mutesoft'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/mutesoft/public_html/fStore/scripts/connect_to_mysql.php on line 11
could not connect to mysql

Comment: You do not need the other lines. Just $mysqli = new mysqli('local...); That is all.

Comment: couldnt manage to do that. doesnt work cant figure it out, but my main problem is solved thanks to you. ty